# mongoose geoindex failure when nested

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bluebird, geo

I'm trying to retrieve a set of mongodb records based on geographic proximity to a given object in another collection. I'm using bluebird to provide promises. But when my query is nested inside the `.then` clause of a find, the geoindex search fails - it seems to neither throw a `.catch` error, nor trigger the code in then.

```
router.post("/alert", function(req, res) {

    User.findOneAsync ({'loc.coordinates' : {
        $near : {
            $geometry : {
                type: "Point",
                "coordinates" : [45.001,45.001]
            },
            $maxDistance : 1000000
        }
    }}).then(function(users) {
        console.log("users actually are " + users)
    })

    Event.findAsync({
        _id : req.body.eventId
    }).then(function(evt) {
        console.log(evt)
        User.findAsync({'loc.coordinates' : {
            $near : {
                $geometry : {
                    type: "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [45.001,45.001]
                },
                $maxDistance : 1000000
            }
        }}).then(function(users) {
            console.log("users are " + users)
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
        console.log('done')
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
    res.send('ok')

})
```

When called, the first query to Users directly will succeed. This is the same query that I can run in mongodb console, and get the same results. But the second one, where an Event is retrieved, none of the code in the `.then(function(evt))` block happens, and the .catch is not triggered either.

This is a bigger problem than it might be, because the coordinates I need to use actually come from the `Event` model, so I need to retrieve that information to actually query `Users`...

the line , `console.log(evt)` does run.

Comment: You know that mongoose 4.x releases support promises natively. Also, why are you nesting `.then()` rather than just continuing the promise chain ( Event -> User -> Result ) in this case?

Comment: Make sure your `Event.findAsync` is indeed RETURNING the promise, if it is, make sure the condition of the promise is good, otherwise it cant be chained.  You might need to manipulate that promise first by either resolving/rejecting it, or you might just need to return it.  If its a good Promise, the next then will fire if its being passed correctly as a promise, No matter which library really.  If your erroring out before the catch, then you need to disect that `Event.findAsync` more carefully because its dying.

Comment: Now what is library dependent is where you put your catches, be careful with that too. This scaffold here shows one way how to catch those errors too https://github.com/wolfdogg/expressBuilder/blob/master/src/controllers/movieController.js

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose 4.x you may plug-in any promise library for Mongoose to utilize. I am not sure if your findAsync method actually returns a promise, even though it has `.then()` methods defined.

From Mongoose docs:

```
 // Use bluebird
 mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Then you can call any Mongoose queries by calling `.find(query).exec();` which returns a full bluebird promise.